# Pandas ValueError on to_datetime operation

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I am processing data from an API using pandas. My goal is to aggregate some numeric data sorted by a specified date column. Any pointers to what I might be doing wrong?

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing
```

This is what I have done:

```py
class CumulativeProcessor:
    def __init__(self, sum_column, sort_by_column):
        self.sum_column = sum_column
        self.sort_by_column = sort_by_column
        self.cumulative_sum = 0

    def get_cum_sum(self, response_data):
        df = pd.DataFrame(response_data['rows'])
        df[self.sort_by_column] = pd.to_datetime(df[self.sort_by_column])
        df = df.sort_values(by=self.sort_by_column)

        df['cumulative_sum'] = df[self.sum_column] + self.cumulative_sum
        self.cumulative_sum = df['cumulative_sum'].iloc[-1]

        return df[[self.sort_by_column, self.aggregation_column, 'cumulative_sum']]


cumulative_processor = CumulativeProcessor(sum_column='sales', sort_by_column='date')

data = {
    "rows": [
        {"sales": 90, "date": "2024-01-01"},
        {"sales": 50, "date": "2024-01-02"},
        {"sales": 150, "date": "2024-01-03"}
    ]
}

results = cumulative_processor.get_cum_sum(data)

print(results)
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you post 2 rows of the real data? Or check if the data are in the right format.

Comment: Please also add what pandas and python you are using so as to replicate the error.

Comment: Hi Orfeas, I am running :

Name: pandas
Version: 2.2.0

and 

Python 3.10.9

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, you should have used the builtin [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

class CumulativeProcessor:
    def __init__(self, sum_column, sort_by_column):
        self.sum_column = sum_column
        self.sort_by_column = sort_by_column
        self.cumulative_sum = 0

    def get_cum_sum(self, response_data):
        df = (pd.DataFrame(response_data['rows'])
                .astype({self.sort_by_column: 'datetime64[ns]'})
                .sort_values(by=self.sort_by_column)
             )

        df['cumulative_sum'] = df[self.sum_column].cumsum()

        return df[[self.sort_by_column, self.sum_column, 'cumulative_sum']]

cumulative_processor = CumulativeProcessor(sum_column='sales', sort_by_column='date')

data = {
    "rows": [
        {"sales": 90, "date": "2024-01-01"},
        {"sales": 50, "date": "2024-01-02"},
        {"sales": 150, "date": "2024-01-03"}
    ]
}

results = cumulative_processor.get_cum_sum(data)
```

Output:

```
        date  sales  cumulative_sum
0 2024-01-01     90              90
1 2024-01-02     50             140
2 2024-01-03    150             290
```